# how to apply tabBarColor in react-native?

Tags: react-native

someone know why it doesn't apply the color i can't see the error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DmFR.png)

i already change the color close and rebuild the project but still don't working

this is the code :

```
<Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        activeColor="#23233c"
        >
        <Tab.Screen
            name="Profile"
            component={PacienteStackProfile}
            options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
            tabBarColor: '#61d27c',
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                <Icon name="ios-person" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
            }}
        />
        </Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Where you want to apply color and which color you wanted to apply?

Comment: tabBarColor , this one #61d27c'

Answer (score 0):

Pass `tabBarOptions` object to your `TabNavigator`

```
<Tab.Navigator
    tabBarOptions={{  // add properties here
    activeTintColor: '#23233c',
    inactiveTintColor: '#424242',
    style: { backgroundColor: '#61d27c' },
   }}>
    <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={PacienteStackProfile}
        options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
        tabBarColor: '#61d27c',
        tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <Icon name="ios-person" color={color} size={26} />
        ),
        }}
    />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: hm i did but still not applying should i remove the options on the screen ?

Comment: You wanted to change the background color of the tabs, am I right?

Comment: yes you are right , i don't know if it is my operating system i am using deepin, but i do exactly what you told me and it doesn't apply it the color

Comment: I don't know what's exactly the problem you have, Could you share some runnable example?